# Por que trocar itens de uma lista com atribuição múltipla não funciona quando uso o "index()" inline na atribuição?

Tags: python, lista

Consigo trocar 'a' e 'b' com este código:

```
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c']  

item = 'a'        # itens que quero localizar e trocar
outro_item = 'b'  #

indice_item       = lista.index(item)       # obtenho a posição de ambos
indice_outro_item = lista.index(outro_item) #

# tento fazer a troca invertendo os índices
lista[indice_item],lista[indice_outro_item]=lista[indice_outro_item],lista[indice_item]

# deu certo
print(lista[0]) # b
print(lista[1]) # a 
print(lista[2]) # c
```

Funcionou: https://ideone.com/2dZvJV

---

Só que se eu não usar as variáveis intermediárias e chamar `index` sempre, mas mantendo a lógica original, a troca não acontece:

```
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c']  

item = 'a'  
outro_item = 'b' 

# aqui estou tentando fazer lista[0,1]=lista[1,0] com indexof diretamente:
lista[lista.index(item)],lista[lista.index(outro_item)]= lista[lista.index(outro_item)],lista[lista.index(item)]

# não trocou!
print(lista[0]) # a
print(lista[1]) # b 
print(lista[2]) # c
```

Qual o motivo do segundo código não funcionar como o primeiro?
https://ideone.com/hs7YOA

Comment: A dúvida é bem interessante, mas é importante [edit] e explicar o que pensou que aconteceria e o  que saiu diferente do esperado, senão depende das pessoas terem que ficar analisndo o código para entender o que você quis fazer, e aí os usuários menos experientes (que seriam os que mais tirariam proveito da dúvida) não acompanhariam.

Comment: É minha primeira pergunta aqui. Editei. Será que ficou mais claro?

Comment: Tinha ficado mais claro, mas não o suficiente. Nunca publique 2x a mesma coisa, sempre edite até resolver o problema. Pelo fato de ter feito 2 postagens e removido, o sistema já  impôs alguns limites na sua conta. Tentei salvar esta aqui detalhando melhor o problema, mas em  próximas perguntas, quando o sistema permitir, tem que tomar  cuidado para evitar novas limitações.

Comment: Perdão. Acabei de entrar na comunidade. Estou ainda conhecendo como funciona. Obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order), expressões são avaliadas da esquerda para a direita, e em caso de atribuições, tudo que está à direita do `=` é avaliado primeiro. Ou seja, em uma expressão como a sua, a ordem de avaliação é:

```
expr3, expr4 = expr1, expr2
```

Primeiro ele avalia `expr1`, depois `expr2`, depois `expr3` (e atribui o valor de `expr1`)  e depois `expr4` (e atribui o valor de `expr2`).

No seu caso, temos:

```
lista[lista.index(item)], lista[lista.index(outro_item)] = lista[lista.index(outro_item)], lista[lista.index(item)]
```

Ou seja, primeiro ele vai avaliar tudo à direita do `=`. Então primeiro é avaliado `lista[lista.index(outro_item)]`, que resulta em `'b'` e depois `lista[lista.index(item)]`, que resulta em `'a'`. O resultado dessas 2 expressões resulta na tupla `('b', 'a')`.

Depois ele avalia a primeira expressão à esquerda do `=`, que é `lista[lista.index(item)]`. Ela resulta em `lista[0]` (já que `'a'` está no índice zero), e este recebe o valor `'b'`. Ou seja, agora a lista é `['b', 'b', 'c']`.

Então, ao avaliar `lista[lista.index(outro_item)]`, o resultado também será `lista[0]`, pois `index` retorna a primeira posição na qual o elemento sendo procurado está. E a primeira posição onde tem um `'b'` agora é zero, por isso `lista[0]` receberá o valor `'a'`, e a lista voltará a ser `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Por isso que o primeiro código funciona, porque você só busca os índices uma vez no início, e ao avaliar as expressões durante a atribuição estes índices não mudam. Já ao chamar `index` toda hora, ele corre o risco de retornar um valor diferente, já que a lista é alterada durante o processo.

---

Podemos ver isso criando uma subclasse de `list`, só para visualizar melhor:

```
class mylist(list):
    def index_dir(self, i):
        x = super().index(i)
        print(f'index_dir({i})={x}')
        return x
    def index_esq(self, i):
        x = super().index(i)
        print(f'index_esq({i})={x}')
        return x
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        x = super().__getitem__(i)
        print(f'get({i})={x}')
        return x
    def __setitem__(self, i, value):
        print(f'set({i})={value}')
        super().__setitem__(i, value)
        print(f'lista agora é: {self}')

lista = mylist(['a', 'b', 'c'])
item = 'a'
outro_item = 'b' 
lista[lista.index_esq(item)],lista[lista.index_esq(outro_item)] = lista[lista.index_dir(outro_item)],lista[lista.index_dir(item)]
```

Criei 2 métodos `index` para deixar claro qual está sendo chamado à direita e à esquerda do `=`. A saída é:

```
index_dir(b)=1
get(1)=b
index_dir(a)=0
get(0)=a
index_esq(a)=0
set(0)=b
lista agora é: ['b', 'b', 'c']
index_esq(b)=0
set(0)=a
lista agora é: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Veja como à direita do `=` ele encontra corretamente os elementos, mas ao fazer a primeira atribuição, a lista é modificada para `['b', 'b', 'c']`, e ao chamar `index` para encontrar o `'b'` ele retorna zero - e por isso é o elemento no índice zero que recebe `'a'.

Agora se eu fizer:

```
indice_item       = lista.index_dir(item)
indice_outro_item = lista.index_dir(outro_item)
lista[indice_item],lista[indice_outro_item]=lista[indice_outro_item],lista[indice_item]
```

A saída é:

```
index_dir(a)=0
index_dir(b)=1
get(1)=b
get(0)=a
set(0)=b
lista agora é: ['b', 'b', 'c']
set(1)=a
lista agora é: ['b', 'a', 'c']
```

Pois os índices só são buscados uma vez, e durante as atribuições eles permanecem com os mesmos valores, portanto cada posição recebe o valor correto.